# Linked list implementation in main

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, dynamic, linked-list

I am new to linked lists.My exercises are something like:"write a function which puts the value x to the end of your linked list".So , my code will look like this:(p is a pointer to the first value)

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    node *next;
};

void LastElement(int x , node * & p)
{
    node *q = new node;
    q = p;
    while (q -> next != NULL)
        q = q -> next;
    
    q->next->info = x;
    q->next->next = NULL;
}
```

My question is:How do i verify this program?What do i write in the main function?Will i create an array or...?

Comment: Write a function that traverses the list and prints each element?

Comment: Try `int main() { node* ls = nullptr; LastElement(0, ls); std::cout << ls->info; }`. Then watch it crash and burn. Then think more about what your function is actually doing. (Draw boxes and arrows on paper.)

Comment: A hint: Just because a variable is of pointer type you don't need to initialize it with `= new XYZ()`, in your case this will leak memory, just use `node *q = p;`

Comment: I'll tell you right now, this code leaks memory, and has undefined behavior regardless of whether you give it `nullptr` or a valid list.

Comment: For your traditional add-at-end [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) provides a good example. Then to see the benefit of O(1) insertions at the end of list, use a `tail` pointer too [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) Or for list operation validation in `main()`, you can do something like [Doubly-Linked List of Integers - Remove Rand Nodes Check](https://pastebin.com/E6WpPjTC)

Comment: Your function in English: Create a node and store its location in `q`. Then replace that location with the location of the list's first node. Then traverse the list until you're sure that `q->next` is `NULL`. Then write into the node at the location `q->next`, which we know is `NULL`.

Comment: Yeah , i did not consider my pointer can be null.I should do: if (p == NULL)  p->info = x p->next = NULL;

Answer (score 0):

You should write a test function that validates that the linked list is of the correct shape. That test function could, for example, walk your linked list in parallel with a `std::vector` and test that elements are the same pairwise and that the length is the same. Its prototype would be something like `bool testEqual(node * list, std::vector<int>)`

Now simply call `LastElement` a few times and then check that the resulting linked list is of the correct shape.

Here is a reference implementation, you can adapt it to arrays if you want:

```
bool testEqual(node * list, const std::vector<int>& test) {
   for (int i = 0; i < test.size() && list != nullptr; i++)
      if (test[i] != list->info) {
          std::cerr << "mismatch at index " << i << std::endl;
          return false;
      }
      list = list->next;
   }
   if (i == test.size() && list == nullptr) {
      return true;
   } else {
      std::cerr << "list is too " << (list == nullptr ? "short" : "long" ) << std::endl;
      return false;
   }
}
```

Simply call this as `testEqual(theList, {1,2,3,4,5})`.

Comment: I don't know what a vector is yet.All i know are functions,arrays,matrices,recursion and pointers and i ve just started linked lists yesterday

Comment: My question is,how will i read some values from the console and assign them to the pointer?If i had a normal array ,i would've done this:for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)cin>>v[i];

Comment: Just `int x; cin >> x;` will read a single number. Generalize that to a for loop that calls your LastElement function

Comment: and how do i assign them to my list?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) { int x; cin >> x; LastElement(x, theList) }`

Comment: oh right.Thank you so much.Is this the only way to assign some values to a list?

Comment: And what about the nod*next?With the LastElement(),next will always get the value NULL

Comment: That is how a linked list is supposed to end, yes. And yes, that is the only way to construct a linked list using the functionality you implemented.

Answer (score 0):

To simply test your code you can do a function like:

```cpp
void check(node *p) {
    while (p != nullptr) {
        std::cout << p->info << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But this function doesn't gonna work with your actual code, because when you do:

```cpp
q->next->info = x;
q->next->next = NULL;
```

Your programme gonna crash, because `q->next` at this moment is null. If you wan't to add a new node whit the value `x` create a new one and put it in like:

```cpp
// generate the need node
node *new_node = new node;
new_node->info = x;
// push the new node to the linked list
node->next = new_node;
```

But if you wan't to modify the last node do:

```cpp
node->info = x;
// but not like you did:
// node->next->info = x;
```

Comment: My question is, how do i assign some values in main to that pointer?When i had array exercises , i just had to do for (i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>v[i] but how do i read values here?

Comment: And i don't think i did wrong,i use another pointer to get to the last value and then i put a new value after it.what does node -> next even mean?